# Declare Before use in C++?

Tags: c++

Following code does compile whereas name "aNumber" is not declared before use.

```
class A
{
    A()
        :aNumber(100)
    {
    }
    void foo()
    {
         aNumber = 0;

    }
    int aNumber;
};
```

If above code compiles then why not following :-

```
A.
class Dummy
{
    void foo(INT);
    typedef int INT;
};
```

B.Default initialization by member variable :-

```
class Dummy
{
    void foo(int y = x);
    int x;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing apples and oranges. The following code is OK:

```
class A {
    A() :aNumber(100) { INT bNumber = aNumber; }
    void foo() { aNumber = INT(42); }
    void bar(int bNumber = INT(1)) { aNumber = bNumber; }
    int aNumber;
    typedef int INT;
};
```

The problem is not *what* you declare, but  where the declarations are used. **Method** definitions, even it they appear lexically inside a class, are compiled as if they are declared inside the class, but defined outside and after the class declaration, and so are default arguments.

Comment: class A { A() :aNumber(aStaicMember) { } int aNumber; void foo(int x = aStaicMember);//aStaicMember not decalred yet static int aStaicMember;//declaration }; int A :: aStaicMember = 100; //definition When above is true then why not typedef.  I am still confused.

Comment: I've shown you, the typedef can also be OK. The important part is _where_ you use the name, not whether the name is a typedef or something else.  chubsdad has quoted the relevant standard text, 9.2/2.

Answer (score 8):

1. In compiling case the order of the elements in the class is irrevelant.
2. In case of a **typedef** the order IS relevant, because a name that was visible outside of the scope might be covered by the new typename.
3. The third example is ill-formed, you cant initialize with a non-static member variable.

Answer (score 2):

For point 1:

> $9.2/2 - "A class is considered a
>   completely-defined object type (3.9)
>   (or complete type) at the closing } of
>   the class-specifier. Within the class
>   member-specification, the class is
>   regarded as complete within function
>   bodies, default arguments and
>   constructor ctor-initializers
>   (including such things in nested
>   classes). Otherwise it is regarded as
>   incomplete within its own class
>   member-specification."

Therefore INT has to be defined before the member function 'foo' is declared.

For point 2:
The reason here is that 'x' is not a static member of 'Dummy'. A non static member of Dummy needs an object expression.

Comment: For point 2 can I use like following :-
class Dummy
{
    void foo(int y = this->x);
    int x;
};
No I can not!!
Why can't I?

Comment: That explains what standard says but I am still unable to know the cause why it is so."$9.2/2".

When "class is regarded as complete within function bodies, default arguments and constructor ctor-initializers" then why not for function declaration??

Comment: @Sudhendu Sharma: 'this' can't be used in the declaration of default arguments as shown because 'this' is valid only within the 'definition' or body of non static class member functions and the constructor initialization list.

Comment: This is also explained by 3.3.6/1. Although you could probably deduce first bullet of `3.3.6/1` by applying `9.2/1` and `3.4.1/8` (which says a name used in a member function "shall be a member of class X or be a member of a base class of X (10.2)," which together with `9.2/1` seems to be sufficient to deduce the scope of a member name without taking into account `3.3.6/1`. So I think your quote may explain it too (I didn't quite see this connection before). I wonder whether 3.3.6/1 first bullet is redundant?

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to process the language in fewer front-to-back passes. Defining things before use improves organization, too.

More substantial definitions can be introduced by a small forward declaration:

```
class Dummy
{
    class bar; // declare first, but not a big deal
    void foo(bar*);
    class bar { ... };
};
```

Sample "B" is not affected by the order of declaration. It illustrates that a default argument cannot name a nonstatic member.

Answer (score 0):

The Standard defines the places where a member name is in scope in certain parts of its members. See `3.3.6/1`:

> - The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following
>     the name’s declarator, but also of all function bodies, default arguments, and constructor ctor-
>     initializers in that class (including such things in nested classes).

"Potential scope" is the scope that the name has if it isn't hidden by any other name. Note that "following the name's declarator" is a not quite correct term, because some declarations are not declared using a declarator (nested class declarations, for example). So C++0x changed this to read

> The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following
>   the *name’s point of declaration*, [...]

Another guy quoted another part of the Standard (`9.2/2`), that requires the class type to be regarded as complete at certain parts. This allows you to create objects of your class within member function bodies, for example.